# Installing Maven repository offline - Artifactory

Tags: maven, repository, offline, artifactory

We are currently testing various products for Continuous Integration, and one of them is Artifactory (for setting up to work with Maven).

To our understanding,
When Maven is configured to work with Artifactory it should not use the internet to download dependencies (Jars, Plugins, Artifacts).
At the first time maven trying to install\build, the Artifactory downloads these files from the internet, and saves them in it's cached local repository for future use.

The problem we have is that we need to install the Artifactory without internet connection, so Artifactory can't go and download the files.

How can we manually tell Artifactory to build it's local repository from files we provide offline?

Answer (score 3):

The offline scenarious are well documented in the [Artifactory User Guide](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Handling+Offline+Scenarios). Your case is the first one - *Organization-wide Offline*.

Once you set Artifactory offline, look at @Itamarb's answer for instructions to populate your repositories.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve your goal:

- If these files are stored in your local machine in a maven layout tree structure dir, you can import this repository directory using the Import Repository from Path feature:
  http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting#ImportingandExporting-RepositoriesImportandExport.

Please note that if the import is done into a releases repository and you are trying to import both releases & snapshots artifacts, the snapshots artifacts will be rejected, and you will have to import this folder again into a snapshot repository.
The same thing happens the other way around (import releases into snapshot will import snapshots artifacts only).

- In case the files stored in your local dist without maven layout tree structure dir, you can archive the dir content and use the ‘Deploy artifacts from archive’ feature:
  http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactsfromArchive
- Another way is by mapping URL (for example by using Apache) to your filesystem and add this URL as a remote repository in Artifactory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first feature is under Admin > Import & Export  ( host:port/artifactory/webapp/#/admin/import_export ).